# How to find the second color in a blend of two RGB colors?

Tags: color, rgb, blending

I would like to restore the original color from a blended RGB color, using a known RGB color.

How can I find it?

[image]

Comment: These colours in the image don't match the RGB numbers you supplied. The light green is #10f7bb which is R:16, G:247, and B:187, and the darker green is #228183 which is R:34, G:129, B:131.  Also how do you want to blend the colours? There are many ways to blend colours.

Comment: The color mismatch was caused by copying and pasting from a screenshot. I fixed it by replacing the image with a PNG file. Thank you! The colors are alpha-blended.

Comment: Check this related question on stack overflow: [How to calculate an rgb colour by specifying an alpha blending amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746899/how-to-calculate-an-rgb-colour-by-specifying-an-alpha-blending-amount)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Billy Kerr comment and by calculating values, I found second color (0.5 alpha blended):

```
R 49
G 13
B 76
```